# How to Dynamically adding fields in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces, dynamic-forms

HI All,

I am desperately looking for the assistance on adding and removing the fields and rows using JSF. I am using ICE Faces for the rich UI look. The following is my problem:

1. I have to add one text box and two buttons (+) and (-) in a row.
2. When user clicks on the + button, one new row should be added with the above components.
3. When user clicks on the - button, the corresponding row should be removed from the display.

I am able to add the individual components like text box and remove it. But, here my challenging point is to add and remove as a row. How would I remove that specific row (instance) from the UI View Root.

I have tried several times, but till now I could not find a solution. Please suggest me the possible solutions.

Thanks in advance,
Krishna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather use a `h:dataTable` (or the IceFaces equivalent `ice:dataTable`) which is backed by a `List<Data>` contining objects which each represents the data of a single row. On *Add* just add a new `Data` item to the list. On *Remove* just remove the selected `Data` item from the list.

#### See also:

- [How to dynamically add new row to table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278353/how-to-dynamically-add-a-row-in-a-table-in-jsf) - detailed answer to similar question
- [Using Datatables](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html) - shows step by step how to use datatables in JSF 1.x.
- [CRUD datatable using @ViewScoped](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html) - simple example of JSF 2.0 CRUD

Comment: HI BalusC,

Thank you for the reply. Do you mean that I can add any component in the DataTable row itself? Do you have any sample code or API for the backing bean? That would be helpful.

I will try that and let you know if I have any doubts.

Thanks,
Krishna

Comment: No, you don't add whole components. That's unnecessarily overcomplicated. Just add a new item to the list/datamodel which the `dataTable` is using. The `datatable` will then display it as a new row. I've updated the answer with some useful links.